# J2ME: For sending image via SMS

Tags: java-me

How can I convert the image from jpeg to binary at sender side & binary to jpeg at receiver side?

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to do it.
Rather stream your image from mobile to your server using webservices and receive it from server from other device

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for some JPEG Encoders written in J2ME. That will help you, however sending it via SMS is an overkill